# How to limit multiple file select in fancyupload?

Tags: php, javascript, mootools, socialengine, fancyupload

I am trying to limit file upload for fancyupload. 
When a user select to upload photo and the dialogue box appears. The user can select only four photos.

Answer (score 0):

[Check fileListMax option](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/)

```
var uploader = new Swiff.Uploader({fileListMax: 4});
```